# Regression model for Cumulative data in R

Tags: r, regression

I am having a daily data for 3-4 months and another variable which is the cumulative sum. It starts with some value on the first day and it keeps on adding and at the end of 3 months, it would be sum of all the values for 3 months.

I want to predict what would be the sum at the end of 6 months.

I am using lm function in R, but it is treating each value as an individual and computing the results.

I just want to know if there is any package in R, which would take into account the cumulative data, produce a model and predict the future?

Thanks

Comment: This is not really a programming question (asking for packages is also considered off-topic). If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical model, you should ask for help at [stats.se] where statistical matters are on-topic.

Comment: Something like this? http://rpubs.com/RomanL/89598

Comment: should you not be using time series data. i would like to graph the data and the cum data to see how it works

Comment: @AjayOhri I tried using the time series data regression. I am not sure of the prediction result. That is why I am wondering whether if there anything for specified for cumulative data.